# How can I use all td space with a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css, height

I would like my `textarea`use all `height` space with css configuration but I can't. Can you, please, help me? thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        td{
            border: solid black 1px;
        }
        textarea{
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <textarea class="textarea1"></textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                a<br/>
                a<br/>
                a<br/>
                a<br/>
                a<br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `td` also needs `height: 100%`. I applied it to all of them, but you might just want to limit it to the one that has the `textarea` depending on how you implement it. Also made the `textarea` `display: block` as that will remove the little bit of white space at the bottom. You could also use `vertical-align: top` instead of `display: block`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    table,tr,td{
      height: 100%;
    }
    td { border: solid black 1px; }
    textarea{
      height: 100%;
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <textarea class="textarea1"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        a<br/> a
        <br/> a
        <br/> a
        <br/> a
        <br/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Alohci ah right, thanks. I'm on a mac and don't have my edge VM's, but FF needs `height: 100%` on the `tr,td`, and I believe edge needs `height: 100%` on the `table,tr,td`. Updated my answer - can you check edge?

Comment: Yes, with the modification, the textarea is about the right size in FF and Edge. - though slightly mispositioned, esp. FF (on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```css
td{
        border: solid black 1px;
        height: 100%;
        padding:0px;
    }
    textarea{
        height: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><textarea></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```